# Is there a way to loop through python dictionaries only with a specific key-value pair?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, key-value

I'm not very experienced with Python + dictionary objects so I think I may be trying to go about this task in the wrong way...

The goal is to search through a database for files with a certain filetype and then return the files that are missing a string in their filename. The files are dict objects which are accessible through scans (also dict objects) which are accessible through sessions (also dict objects!).

I'm testing by looping through the scans for just one session and this is what is working currently:

```
for scan in session_data[1539].scans.values():
    for file in scan.files.values():
        if file.file_format == "NIFTI" and "*input_*" not in file._cache['id']:
            print(scan)
            print(file)
```

The problem is: to every one file of the type I am interested in, there are thousands of files with a different file type that I'm not interested in that are being looped through and slowing down the process to the point this method will not work when I add looping through all the sessions. Is there some way for me to loop through only the files with file_format : NIFTI and ignore the others? Something like this (but functional, lol):

```
for scan in session_data[1539].scans.values():
    for file in scan.files['file_format':'NIFTI'].values():
        if "*input_*" not in file._cache['id']:
            print(scan)
            print(file)
```

These are the properties and methods for the files dictionary:

```
print(dir(scan_data[1].files[1]))
['SECONDARY_LOOKUP_FIELD', '_CONTAINED_IN', '_DISPLAY_IDENTIFIER', '_HAS_FIELDS', '_XSI_TYPE', '__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '__xsi_type__', '_abc_impl', '_cache', '_caching', '_fieldname', '_fields', '_overwrites', '_parent', '_path', '_uri', '_xnat_session', 'caching', 'cat_id', 'clearcache', 'collection', 'data', 'del_', 'delete', 'digest', 'download', 'download_stream', 'external_uri', 'fieldname', 'file_content', 'file_format', 'file_size', 'file_tags', 'full_data', 'fulldata', 'fulluri', 'get', 'get_object', 'id', 'logger', 'mset', 'open', 'parent', 'path', 'query', 'set', 'size', 'uri', 'xnat_session', 'xpath']
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve de filename of each file? If so, your could use Python's `endswith()` function.

Comment: As far as I can think, with a dictionary data structure, you will have to visit each value to check if it is equal to `NIFTI` or not.  The same observation goes for any method that does not preprocess the collection -- you have to visit each string to perform a comparison. A simple fix might be to use multiple threads to do this in parallel if you have sufficient amounts of memory.

Comment: @DiegoHernandezHerrera _cache['id'] gives the filename but I'm not sure how that would help me to not loop through every file?

Comment: @Sophie I'll give you an example. If `text = "something.txt"` then `print(text.endswith('.txt'))` will return `True`. In the same way, you could check with the `endswith()` function if any filename ends with .nii or whatever suffix the NIFTI files use.

Comment: @Unni Thanks for the feedback, I will look into doing it in parallel :)

Comment: @DiegoHernandezHerrera: It wouldn't solve the original problem. You need to loop through each file to check if `endswith()` returns `True`.